# Can't change GtkWindow size when using GtkBuilder

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3, glade

I'm using `GtkBuilder` with a Glade XML file. I want to change the size of the window to fullscreen without using the `gtk_window_fullscreen` method (because this needs to work without a window manager), so I get the screen dimensions and make the window that size. This used to work when I created the widgets programmatically, however when I switched to Glade/`GtkBuilder` the window is the same small size as it was in Glade editor. Do I have to do something differently with `GtkBuilder`? Here's the code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "dm.ui", NULL);

    GObject *window = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window");

    // Make full screen
    GdkScreen *screen = gdk_screen_get_default();
    gint height = gdk_screen_get_height(screen);
    gint width = gdk_screen_get_width(screen);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), width, height);

    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_main();
}
```

Here's the XML file, dm.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkLayout" id="main_layout">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="user_text_field">
            <property name="width_request">162</property>
            <property name="height_request">31</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="margin_right">42</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">175</property>
            <property name="y">73</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="user_label">
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Username</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">71</property>
            <property name="y">46</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="password_label">
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Password</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">72</property>
            <property name="y">103</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="password_text_field">
            <property name="width_request">162</property>
            <property name="height_request">31</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">177</property>
            <property name="y">129</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using

```
void gtk_widget_set_size_request(GtkWidget *widget, gint width, gint height);
```

or you can use Glade to adjust GtkWindow properties of "default-width" and "default-height" rather than hardcode it. 
Let me know the result.
p.s : that is why i hate Glade :(